# Check if the page exist in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is there a way to check if a certain page stored in a string exist in Xamarin Forms?

for instance;

```
string pageName = "WelcomePage";
```

This doesn't work.

```
bool IsPageExist = Xamarin.Forms.IPageContainer.PageExists(pageName);
```

Comment: The `INavigation.NavigationStack` contains a collection of all active pages. You can search this collection for find your page.

Comment: what do you mean by if a page "exists"?  Is there an instance already on the nav stack?  Or something else?

Comment: Same thread here :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71965708/xamarin-prism-get-the-list-of-register-pages.